# One URL for two SharePoint site - make online based on availability

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, iis, alternate-access-mapping

I have two SharePoint site, Site A is pointing to default port 80 (`http://mysite.company.com/sites/mypage`) which is pointing to database1. I have created a replica of SiteA as a intranet site i.e. SiteB (`http:severname:7878/sites/mypage`) which is pointing to database2.
Now, very frequently we are making changes to SiteA and database1. Because of that we would like to keep siteA offline but want user to access SiteB using siteA URL.

As I have no understanding about SharePoint I googled and found out that via AAM I can give 2 URL to same SharePoint. But what if I want to give same URL to two different SharePoint site.

I am planning to place App_Offline.html in the virual directory to SiteA so that it will become offline and user will be redirected to SiteB using SiteA URL.

Is there any way to make a switch between one site to another?

Answer (score 1):

Well if  you want to access the site B with site A url you need to update your DNS, extend the WebApp B so it recognises URL A and configure AAM. When you want to access site A with URL just add on the client machine entry in your host file.

Another option would be to create some routing rules on load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1. I am trying to add intrenet zone in site2 using site1 URL but I am getting an error. "Site1 is already assigned as a default, you need to first remove mapping". I am confused. Is there any step by step procedure related to my requirement? I am complete newbie in SharePoint.

Comment: Ahh you right, if you have already web app with that url you cannot use that url in another app. So you would have to extend App1 to new url, Delete the other zone with url you want to add to app2. But in this scenario you will not be able to access App1 with original url.